# Python ImportError returning a 0 exit code in shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, exit-code

```
peters-mbp:python_proj me$ python api_tests.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/python_proj/api_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requestssss
ImportError: No module named requestssss


peters-mbp:python_proj me$ echo $?
0
```

How can I make it return a non-zero exit code?

Comment: That's a bug, not an error condition. Fix the import.

Comment: `python -c 'import requestssss'; echo $?` returns `1`. Thus, reproducing this issue requires something you haven't included in your question.

Comment: (that something could potentially be a shell function or alias that's overriding your exit status -- using `set -x` would help make that evident, if true. Otherwise, it's presumably something going on inside the Python interpreter, hence the need for a reproducer).

Comment: @chepner Obviously. I need these types of errors to fail with a non-zero exit  code for CI purposes. I just misspelt that library as an example.

Comment: @Strobe_, ...so, where are we on (do you have any intention of) amending this question to provide steps someone else can use to reproduce the issue? (Have you tested whether the `python -c 'import nonexisting'; echo $?` approach -- as opposed to using an `api_tests.py` script that nobody but you has source to -- reproduces the problem for you?)

Comment: @Strobe_, ...similarly: `cd "$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/test.XXXXXX")" && { printf '%s\n' '#!/usr/bin/env python' 'import nonexisting'  >test.py && python test.py; echo "Exit status is: $?"; rm -rf -- "$PWD"; cd -; }` emits `Exit status is: 1` when I run it, so it's not `python -c ...` vs running from a script in a file that makes the difference.